# Iterating over a large unicode list taking a long time?

Tags: list, python-2.7, unicode, iteration, maya

I'm working with the program Autodesk Maya.
I've made a naming convention script that will name each item in a certain convention accordingly. However I have it list every time in the scene, then check if the chosen name matches any current name in the scene, and then I have it rename it and recheck once more through the scene if there is a duplicate.

However, when i run the code, it can take as long as 30 seconds to a minute or more to run through it all. At first I had no idea what was making my code run slow, as it worked fine in a relatively low scene amount. But then when i put print statements in the check scene code, i saw that it was taking a long time to check through all the items in the scene, and check for duplicates.

The ls() command provides a unicode list of all the items in the scene. These items can be relatively large, up to a thousand or more if the scene has even a moderate amount of items, a normal scene would be several times larger than the testing scene i have at the moment (which has about 794 items in this list).

Is this supposed to take this long? Is the method i'm using to compare things inefficient? I'm not sure what to do here, the code is taking an excessive amount of time, i'm also wondering if it could be anything else in the code, but this seems like it might be it.

Here is some code below.

```
class Name(object):
    """A naming convention class that runs passed arguments through user
    dictionary, and returns formatted string of users input naming convention.
    """

    def __init__(self, user_conv):
        self.user_conv = user_conv
        # an example of a user convention is '${prefix}_${name}_${side}_${objtype}'

    @staticmethod
    def abbrev_lib(word):
        # a dictionary of abbreviated words is here, takes in a string
        # and returns an abbreviated string, if not found return given string


    @staticmethod
    def check_scene(name):
        """Checks entire scene for same name. If duplicate exists,

        Keyword Arguments:
        name -- (string) name of object to be checked
        """

        scene = ls()
        match = [x for x in scene if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable)
                        and (name in x)]
        if not match:
            return name
        else:
            return ''

    def convert(self, prefix, name, side, objtype):
        """Converts given information about object into user specified convention.

        Keyword Arguments:
        prefix -- what is prefixed before the name
        name -- name of the object or node
        side -- what side the object is on, example 'left' or 'right'
        obj_type -- the type of the object, example 'joint' or 'multiplyDivide'
        """
        prefix = self.abbrev_lib(prefix)
        name = self.abbrev_lib(name)
        side = ''.join([self.abbrev_lib(x) for x in side])
        objtype = self.abbrev_lib(objtype)
        i = 02
        checked = ''
        subs = {'prefix': prefix, 'name': name, 'side':
            side, 'objtype': objtype}
        while self.checked == '':
            newname = Template (self.user_conv.lower())
            newname = newname.safe_substitute(**subs)
            newname = newname.strip('_')
            newname = newname.replace('__', '_')
        checked = self.check_scene(newname)
        if checked == '' and i < 100:
            subs['objtype'] = '%s%s' %(objtype, i)
            i+=1
        else:
            break
    return checked
```

Comment: Have you done any profiling, to find out where the time's being taken?

Comment: Not sure how to do that, still kind of new to python and using an IDE. I'll see if i can look that up though.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: Yeh, i used cProfile.run(re.compile(proxarm.arm_system('x', False, False))) instead of the proxyarm.arm_system('x', False, False) and it didn't give me anything new in my console window, just ran the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you running this many times? You are potentially trolling a list of several hundred or a few thousand items for each iteration inside `while self.checked ==''`, which would be a likely culprit.  FWIW prints are also very slow in Maya, especially if you're printing a long list - so doing that many times will definitely be slow no matter what.

I'd try a couple of things to speed this up:

1. limit your searches to one type at a time - why troll through hundreds of random nodes if you only care about `MultiplyDivide` right now?
2. Use a set or a dictionary to search, rather than a list - sets and dictionaries use hashsets and are faster for lookups
3. If you're worried about maintining a naming convetion, definitely design it to be resistant to Maya's default behavior which is to append numeric suffixes to keep names unique. Any naming convention which doesn't support this will be a pain in the butt for all time, because you can't prevent Maya from doing this in the ordinary course of business. On the other hand if you use that for differntiating instances you don't need to do any uniquification at all  - just use rename() on the object and capture the result. The weakness there is that Maya won't rename for global uniqueness, only local - so if you want to make unique node name for things that are not siblings you have to do it yourself.

Here's some cheapie code for finding unique node names:

```
def get_unique_scene_names (*nodeTypes):
    if not nodeTypes:
        nodeTypes = ('transform',)
    results = {}
    for longname in cmds.ls(type = nodeTypes, l=True):
        shortname = longname.rpartition("|")[-1]
        if not shortname in results:
            results[shortname] = set()
        results[shortname].add(longname)    
    return results

def add_unique_name(item, node_dict):
    shortname = item.rpartition("|")[-1]
    if shortname in node_dict:
        node_dict[shortname].add(item)
    else:
        node_dict[shortname] = set([item])

def remove_unique_name(item, node_dict):
    shortname = item.rpartition("|")[-1]
    existing  = node_dict.get(shortname, [])
    if item in existing:
        existing.remove(item)


def apply_convention(node, new_name, node_dict):
    if not new_name in node_dict:
        renamed_item = cmds.ls(cmds.rename(node, new_name), l=True)[0]
        remove_unique_name(node, node_dict)
        add_unique_name ( renamed_item, node_dict)
        return renamed_item
    else:
        for n in range(99999):
            possible_name = new_name + str(n + 1)
            if not possible_name in node_dict:
                renamed_item =  cmds.ls(cmds.rename(node, possible_name), l=True)[0]
                add_unique_name(renamed_item, node_dict)
                return renamed_item
        raise RuntimeError, "Too many duplicate names"
```

To use it on a particular node type, you just supply the right would-be name when calling `apply_convention()`. This would rename all the joints in the scene (naively!) to 'jnt_X' while keeping the suffixes unique. You'd do something smarter than that, like your original code did - this just makes sure that leaves are unique:

```
joint_names=  get_unique_scene_names('joint')               

existing = cmds.ls( type='joint', l = True)
existing .sort()
existing .reverse()
# do this to make sure it works from leaves backwards!

for item in existing :
    apply_convention(item,  'jnt_', joint_names)

# check the uniqueness constraint by looking for how many items share a short name in the dict:
for d in joint_names:
    print d, len (joint_names[d])
```

But, like i said, plan for those damn numeric suffixes, maya makes them all the time without asking for permission so you can't fight em :(

Comment: I send strings to it, then it sends out a string for the name, then i use the rename() as you said to rename a newly created object. So that isn't much of a problem. As for the nodes, it could be a different node for anything, lets say i have a plus minus average node names 'average_pma' but for some reason a different node was named 'average_pma'. I want to account for that, especially considering i'm not only naming curves, but groups, locators, utility nodes, and even shaders.

Comment: You can make the original collection as complex as you want by adding multiple types, just at the cost of slower performance

Comment: But yes, i suppose speed is more important so i'll switch my script to account for that. I'll just try to use the object type thats given.

Comment: Working on implementing it now, will take a bit but i'll tell you how it works out when i'm done.

Comment: Also whats your opinion on how i handle the formatting of the convention, i updated the script above to give the full code. I wanted to have it so a user could input their own convention for the script, so if they want it to be prefix_name_side_objtype then it will input it like that. There are some troubles like how to handle extra underscores that i've gotten aruond with a hacky thing, or uppercase formatting, but is there an easier or more flexible way to go about this?

Comment: Most of it is just style, the only hard constraints are keep the numbers at the end and no special characters.

 I personally use lower_underscores for everything except left and right (because I have bad eyes and L/R is easier to differentiate for me :).  From a code standpoint, you could pass the actual convention function in - that would let you use the same structure for lots of different conventions, each with its own rules. Unders are especially useful because you can split on them and get a set of tokens like ('l', 'hand', 'ik', 'pv') if you need to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running `ls` for each and every `name`, you should run it once and store that result into a `set` (an unordered list - slightly faster). Then check against that when you run `check_scene`

```
def check_scene(self, name):
    """Checks entire scene for same name. If duplicate exists,

    Keyword Arguments:
    name -- (string) name of object to be checked
    """

    if not hasattr(self, 'scene'):
        self.scene = set(ls())

    if name not in self.scene:
        return name
    else:
        return ''
```